# Current Location and direction on map Blackberry(Os 6, 7 and 10)

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-maps, blackberry-os6

i want to integrate map on(Blackberry 6 7 and 10) and show current location and direction route between two locations inside  my app which one should i use.

1.Google map

or

2.blackberry native map

is there any sample please provide me the link

Comment: BlackBerry 6, 7 are completely different from 10, so it will be hard. And I think BlackBerry native maps should work the best

Comment: for OS < 10 you can use google maps. Refer-http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2013/07/showing-google-maps-in-blackberry.html